# Regexp for a double

Tags: regex, c++-cli

I have got this regexp `"^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$")` to match a double number or an integer number in visual C++ but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

This is how I am applying the code:

```
if (System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex::IsMatch(e0, "^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$")){
     e0_val = System::Convert::ToDouble(e0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Give an example.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov +1, "doesn't work gimme teh codez" is not a good question form.

Comment: Whitespace at the start or end perhaps? Can you post the code that's using it?

Comment: when I try to use it to validate a number input in a textbox it returns a message indicating that the number 0.16 is not a number

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI? If so, why don't you use Double::TryParse instead?

Comment: @Mithrandir thanks for that Double::TryParse...just what I need.

Comment: `^[0-9]*?(.[0-9]+)$` this is worked for me.  valid cases :  123.123  123 .123. invalid cases: 123.123.123 123.   .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the regex per se, it's your escaping that's at fault.  You need to double escape the `\` character since that's also a C++ string escape character.

Additionaly there is an edge case where this regex would think that `1.` is a valid floating pointer number.  So you might be better off with `/^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$` which eliminates that possibility.

Answer (score 22):

the regexp above is not perfect since it accepts "09" which is not a valid number. a better expression would be:

```
"^(-?)(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\\.[0-9]+)?$"
```

where:

```
1. is an optional negative sign;
2. is zero or a valid non-zero integer;
4. is the optional fracture part;
```

in theory, the fracture part should be written as "(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?"
instead, because a number must not have tailing zeroes. in practice, the source string might have been created with a fixed number of digits e.g:

```
printf("%.1f", x);
```

so it might easily end with a zero character. and, of course, these are all fixed point representations, not the doubles themselves. a double number can
be written as -1.23e-4 as well instead of -0.000123.

Comment: 09 is a valid number and trailing zeros are allowed. Eg 9.45000 is a valid number.

Comment: @dannyhut: it depends. usually 09 and 08 are not valid decimal numbers. a zero prefix means octal notation, and allowed digits after the prefix are 0-7 only.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to place 0's in front of a decimal number. We mostly don't because its unnecessary but it is fine. 09 is a 0 is the ten's column and a 9 in the one's column. This also applies to 0 after the numbers in the exponent of a number. Even many programming languages not just English have no problems with this.  Examples include dates, phone numbers, prices in menus and anywhere padding is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not a direct answer, just useful information. The regexp:

```
std::regex rx(R"(^([+-]?(?:[[:d:]]+\.?|[[:d:]]*\.[[:d:]]+))(?:[Ee][+-]?[[:d:]]+)?$)");
```

matches strings:

```
"1", "0", "10",
"1000.1", "+1",
"+10", "-10", "1.",
".1", "1.1", "+1.",
"-1.", "+.1", "-.1",
"009", "+009", "-009",
"-01e0", "+01E0", "+1e-1",
"+1e+1", "+1.e1", "1E1",
"1E+1", "0.001e-12", "0.111111111111111"
```

and does not matches the next strings:

```
".", "1a", "++1",
"+-1", "+", "-.",
"-", "--1.", "1.e.1",
"1e.1", "0+.e0"
```

The first ones look like valid values for the `double` type in C++, e.g. `double test = +009.e+10` is OK.

Play it in ideone.com: https://ideone.com/ooF8sG

Answer (score 4):

**/^[0-9]+.[0-9]+$** : use this for doubles.

accepts 123.123 types.

Comment: It should be `\.` otherwise you'd accept any decimal separator

Answer (score 3):

```
/^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$/
```

Regex above works for doubles such as "45.5", "12", ".12"

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+)?\.(\d+)?
```

Regex above works for doubles such as **"45.5"**, **"12."**, **".12"**

Comment: it also accepts a single period character, which is definitely not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

```
    constexpr char double_regex_s[53] =
        "^" // accept only if it matches the beginning of the string
        "(-?)" // accept a single optional negation
        "(0|([1-9][0-9]*))" // number is either zero or some integer that does not start with zero
        "(" // begin optional decimals
            "\\." // require a dot
            "[0-9]+" // any digit is fine, but at least one (std::atof does not require but chrome requires digits after dot)
        ")?" // end optional decimals
        "(" // begin optional scientific exponent
            "[eE]" // require an e or E
            "[-+]?" // accept optional plus or minus
            "[0-9]+" // any digit is fine (tested in chrome JSON.parse(1E000003) works)
        ")?" // end optional scientific exponent
        "$" // accept only if it matches up to the end of the string
        ;
```