# Antlr lexer rule to tokenize float/double

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304961/1834787) to tokenize a double in Antlr but apparently this regex is not getting understood by Antlr.

```
Number: (-?)(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\\.[0-9]+)?;
```

Error:

```
syntax error: '-' came as a complete surprise to me 
syntax error: '?' came as a complete surprise to me
syntax error: '0' came as a complete surprise to me
syntax error: '\' came as a complete surprise to me 
syntax error: '\' came as a complete surprise to me 
syntax error: '-' came as a complete surprise to me 
syntax error: '?' came as a complete surprise to me
syntax error: '0' came as a complete surprise to me
syntax error: '\' came as a complete surprise to me 
syntax error: '\' came as a complete surprise to me
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR Lexer rules somewhat resemble REGEX, but definitely are not REGEXs.

Try:

```
Number: '-'?('0'|[1-9][0-9]*)('.'[0-9]+)?;
```

Characters need to be enclosed in `'` marks (with the exception of set notation (characters between `[` and `]`)